# gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit auto checked checkbox

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using angularjs and ui.grid. I've some problem. I want checkbox auto checked after I edit cell..
I've Tried So Many Times to code auto checked after edit cell but still not success. How the best way to solve it.

this my demo in [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/tVXPtl10nNFbwwbP)

Example code

```
    $scope.checkboxData = false;

 $scope.checkboxCheck = checkboxCheck;
         function checkboxCheck(params, statusCheck) {
            console.log("test checked");
            console.log(params);
            console.log(statusCheck);

            
        
         }


  $scope.gridOptions = {

    enableCellEdit: false, 

    enableCellEditOnFocus: true,

    cellEditableCondition: function($scope) {

      return $scope.row.entity.isActive;

    }

  };

    $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
    
        {name: 'isActive', displayName: 'Edit Status', enableColumnMenu: false, cellTemplate: 'cellTemplate_lock.html'}, // displays isActive status as a button and allow toggling it 
    
        {name: 'name', enableCellEdit: true}, // editing is enabled for this column, but will be overridden per row by cellEditableCondition
    
        {name: 'company', enableCellEdit: true},
          { displayName: 'Select', name: 'checkbox', field: 'checkboxData', enableFiltering: false, enableCellEdit: false, cellTemplate: '<span style="margin-left: 0px;"><input class="Checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkboxData" ng-model="checkboxData" ng-click="grid.appScope.checkboxCheck(row.entity, checkboxData)" id="{{row.entity.seq_no}}"></input><label for="{{row.entity.seq_no}}"><span></span></label></span>',width: 60 } // same for this column
    
      ];
    
    
      $scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi) {
    
        $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    
        gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit($scope, function(rowEntity, colDef, newValue, oldValue) {
    
          $scope.msg.lastCellEdited = 'ID: ' + rowEntity.id + ', Column: ' + colDef.name + ', New Value: ' + newValue + ', Old Value: ' + oldValue;
    
          $scope.$apply();
    
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to add this :
rowEntity.checkboxData = true;

Answer (score 0):

I've updated the code, you have to bind the correct value in ng-model for the checkbox. Please see the below image for the updated code of the checkbox column.

[image]

Comment: could you share link plinkr that you have edit?

Comment: Actually, I want checkbox checked after edit cell company column

Comment: Here is a plinkr link: https://plnkr.co/edit/MBmXXQpvIImka1sR?preview